# Pros and Cons...Constants as a value or as a reference?

Tags: c++

What are the pros and cons of both approaches:

`Case#1: const int& x = 5;`

vs

`Case#2: const int x = 5;`

I know that in Case#1, x refers to an location in the executable's text, and I believe so does x in Case#2.

Why would you use one and not the other?

Comment: If you're really only interested in the case of `int`, I think this is answerable, but in the general case, I highly doubt that there is an answer that isn't an opinion. Or, to put it in different words: I think this is way too broad.

Comment: I was fairly certain all constants are stored in the .text (.data or .rodata) section of the executable which is read-only.. Never heard of constants being on the stack before :l  Maybe I'm wrong I guess..

Comment: mm, Maybe you are correct :$

Comment: @stefan I actually don't see any difference between both cases. is there a performance issue here?

Comment: Write a small example program that uses both approaches and look at the generated assembly. I've never used case #1 and in my experience with case #2 the value appears as a literal in the executable code and doesn't even generate a separate stack variable.

Comment: @Kam Well I actually don't see the point of referencing here. But it certainly feels odd to me. Why would you hold a reference to a temporary and say "this is const" instead of saying "this is a const object"? When in doubt, you can always look at the generated assembly. Optimizations aside, the reference version will generate more code, hence the trivial conclusion would be, that it's useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using gcc explorer:

Case 1 (-O3):

```
main:                                   # @main
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    ret

global_constant:
    .quad   reference temporary for global_constant

reference temporary for global_constant:
    .long   2048                    # 0x800
```

Case 2 (-O3):

```
main:                                   # @main
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    ret
```

Using Mingw 4.8.1 g++ Windows 8 (it is the same result just looks more messy)..

Case 1 (-O3):

```
    .file   "TestConstantsAsm.cpp"
    .def    __main; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section    .text.startup,"x"
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  main
    .def    main;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   main
main:
    subq    $40, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 40
    .seh_endprologue
    call    __main
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $40, %rsp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .p2align 4,,15
    .def    _GLOBAL__sub_I_global_constant; .scl    3;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   _GLOBAL__sub_I_global_constant
_GLOBAL__sub_I_global_constant:
    .seh_endprologue
    leaq    _ZGR15global_constant0(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, global_constant(%rip)
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .section    .ctors,"w"
    .align 8
    .quad   _GLOBAL__sub_I_global_constant
    .globl  global_constant
    .bss
    .align 16
global_constant:
    .space 8
    .data
    .align 4
_ZGR15global_constant0:
    .long   2048
    .ident  "GCC: (rev5, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.8.1"
```

Case 2 (-O3):

```
    .file   "TestConstantsAsm.cpp"
    .def    __main; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section    .text.startup,"x"
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  main
    .def    main;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   main
main:
    subq    $40, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 40
    .seh_endprologue
    call    __main
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $40, %rsp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .ident  "GCC: (rev5, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.8.1"
```

Without (-O3), the 2nd case is still better than the first case. It always is..

The commands I used were:

```
g++ -S -O3 TestConstantsAsm.cpp
g++ -S -O2 TestConstantsAsm.cpp
g++ -S -O TestConstantsAsm.cpp
```

and the program was:

```
const int& global_constant = 2048;

int main()
{
}
```

and

```
const int global_constant = 2048;

int main()
{
}
```

Even if you `std::cout<<global_constant<<"\n";` within main (in both cases), the assembly for case 2 is still cleaner than case 1.

Answer (score 0):

*Using Visual C++ 2013, compiled in debug mode.*

### Case 1

The following code:

```c++
const int& VALUE = 2048;

int main() {
    int A = VALUE;
    return 0;
}
```

...produces this assembly output:

```
     1: const int& VALUE = 2048;
013F1380 55                   push        ebp  
013F1381 8B EC                mov         ebp,esp  
013F1383 81 EC C0 00 00 00    sub         esp,0C0h  
013F1389 53                   push        ebx  
013F138A 56                   push        esi  
013F138B 57                   push        edi  
013F138C 8D BD 40 FF FF FF    lea         edi,[ebp-0C0h]  
013F1392 B9 30 00 00 00       mov         ecx,30h  
013F1397 B8 CC CC CC CC       mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
013F139C F3 AB                rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
013F139E C7 05 34 91 3F 01 00 08 00 00 mov         dword ptr ds:[13F9134h],800h  
013F13A8 C7 05 30 91 3F 01 34 91 3F 01 mov         dword ptr ds:[13F9130h],13F9134h  
013F13B2 5F                   pop         edi  
013F13B3 5E                   pop         esi  
013F13B4 5B                   pop         ebx  
013F13B5 8B E5                mov         esp,ebp  
013F13B7 5D                   pop         ebp  
013F13B8 C3                   ret  

(...)

     2: 
     3: int main() {
00C42280 55                   push        ebp  
00C42281 8B EC                mov         ebp,esp  
00C42283 81 EC CC 00 00 00    sub         esp,0CCh  
00C42289 53                   push        ebx  
00C4228A 56                   push        esi  
00C4228B 57                   push        edi  
00C4228C 8D BD 34 FF FF FF    lea         edi,[ebp-0CCh]  
00C42292 B9 33 00 00 00       mov         ecx,33h  
00C42297 B8 CC CC CC CC       mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
00C4229C F3 AB                rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
     4:     int A = VALUE;
00C4229E A1 30 91 C4 00       mov         eax,dword ptr ds:[00C49130h]  
00C422A3 8B 08                mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]  
00C422A5 89 4D F8             mov         dword ptr [A],ecx  
     5:     return 0;
00C422A8 33 C0                xor         eax,eax  
     6: }
00C422AA 5F                   pop         edi  
     6: }
00C422AB 5E                   pop         esi  
00C422AC 5B                   pop         ebx  
00C422AD 8B E5                mov         esp,ebp  
00C422AF 5D                   pop         ebp  
00C422B0 C3                   ret
```

In case 1, the value 2048 (0x800) is stored in memory, which is accessed when the constant is referenced in the main code.

### Case 2

The following code:

```c++
const int VALUE = 2048;

int main() {
    int A = VALUE;
    return 0;
}
```

...produces this assembly output:

```
     1: const int VALUE = 2048;
     2: 
     3: int main() {
00F02280 55                   push        ebp  
00F02281 8B EC                mov         ebp,esp  
00F02283 81 EC CC 00 00 00    sub         esp,0CCh  
00F02289 53                   push        ebx  
00F0228A 56                   push        esi  
00F0228B 57                   push        edi  
00F0228C 8D BD 34 FF FF FF    lea         edi,[ebp-0CCh]  
00F02292 B9 33 00 00 00       mov         ecx,33h  
00F02297 B8 CC CC CC CC       mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
00F0229C F3 AB                rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
     4:     int A = VALUE;
00F0229E C7 45 F8 00 08 00 00 mov         dword ptr [A],800h  
     5:     return 0;
00F022A5 33 C0                xor         eax,eax  
     6: }
00F022A7 5F                   pop         edi  
00F022A8 5E                   pop         esi  
00F022A9 5B                   pop         ebx  
00F022AA 8B E5                mov         esp,ebp  
00F022AC 5D                   pop         ebp  
00F022AD C3                   ret
```

In case 2, no code is generated for the global constant declaration itself. When the constant is used, it is simply a "move immediate" instruction which inserts the value 2048 (0x800) directly into the variable. If the constant is not used, it will not appear in the assembly at all.